# android ndk-build error on ubuntu 12.10 32 bit

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-ndk

i have downloaded the latest android ndk r8b on my ubuntu 12.10 beta 2 .
i have included the ndk directory in the PATH variable (when i write ndk-b in terminal and hit tab it auto-completes it) .
but when i try :

cd android-ndk/samples/san-angeles/jni
ndk-build

i get this error:

```
make: /home/mixpro/Android/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Command not found  
make: /home/mixpro/Android/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Command not found  
Compile thumb  : sanangeles <= importgl.c
make: /home/mixpro/Android/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Command not found  
make: *** [/home/mixpro/Android/android-ndk/samples/san-angeles/obj/local/armeabi/objs/sanangeles/importgl.o] Error 127
```

when checking the /android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin directory using ls i get:
`arm-linux-androideabi-addr2line  arm-linux-androideabi-g++

arm-linux-androideabi-gdbtui   arm-linux-androideabi-size

arm-linux-androideabi-c++filt    arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-4.6.x-google

  arm-linux-androideabi-gprof    arm-linux-androideabi-strings

arm-linux-androideabi-cpp        arm-linux-androideabi-gcov

arm-linux-androideabi-readelf arm-linux-androideabi-elfedit

arm-linux-androideabi-gdb    arm-linux-androideabi-run`

meaning there is no arm-linux-androideabi-gcc in the directory

Comment: maybe i should do something in ubuntu ?!? cause i downloaded ndk r8 ,  and before ubuntu 12.10 r8 was working fine but not now with ubuntu 12.10 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid that somehow you got arm-linux-androideabi-addr2line arm-linux-androideabi-gcc deleted. On linux, it is just a symlink to arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-4.6.x-google, so it's very easy to restore it. But maybe, to be on the safe side, it's worthwhile to reinstall NDK.

Comment: wow , thanks a lot , i have been untaring the tar.bz2 with the default compress software in ubuntu and it seems that it doesn't extract sym link , so i tried untaring it using terminal $: tar jxf filename.tar.bz2 and it worked , thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

you should create symbolic link like this : ln -s /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.7  "/home/sofien/Bureau/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc"